# How to use java8 stream filter() method under condition?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wonder how to choose to use stream filter under condition. That is, whether I can use fiter or not decided by a variable.

My original codes are:

```
if (keyword == null) {
        return list.parallelStream()
            //not using filter
            .map(...)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return list.parallelStream()
            .filter(dto -> dto.getString().contains(keyword))
            .map(...)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So can I mix the two return statements into one? Like

```
return list.parallelStream()
            .filterIfKeywordNonNull(dto -> dto.getString().contains(keyword))
            .map(...)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can write your own `public boolean validate(String str) { if (keyword == null) { return true; } else { return str.getString().contains(keyword);}}` method. and use it inside `.fileter(dto -> validate(dto))`.

Comment: @tonyhoan or just `public boolean validate(String str) { return keyword == null || str.getString().contains(keyword); }`

Comment: @Holger can use your short way but I still prefer my way because It's clearer, more readable and easier to debug :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add the `keyword` test to your filter. Like,

```
return list.parallelStream()
        .filter(dto -> keyword == null || dto.getString().contains(keyword))
        .map(...)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For improved efficiency, it's also possible to build the `Stream` once and save it a temporary variable using a ternary. Like,

```
Stream<T> stream = (keyword == null) ? list.parallelStream() :
    list.parallelStream().filter(dto -> dto.getString().contains(keyword));
return stream.map(...).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could use the ternary in the return, but then you have to repeat the `map` and `collect` calls.

Comment: Not the most efficient, but probably the cleanest way.

Comment: Or you can do `.filter(keyword == null ? dto -> true : dto -> dto.getString().contains(keyword))`.

Comment: @shmosel what would you gain with that?

Comment: @JoseDaSilva It would only evaluate `keyword == null` once.

Comment: @shmosel If we're using a ternary, why not just put it on the `return`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't see how you could do it cleanly.

Comment: I think that the price is not that high for a more readable piece of code

Comment: @shmosel See edit. Maybe not the cleanest thing in the world. But not too bad (IMO).

Comment: You don’t need to repeat `map` and `collect` with “ternary in the return”; you can use braces: `return (keyword == null? list.parallelStream(): list.parallelStream().filter(dto -> dto.getString().contains(keyword))) .map(...) .collect(Collectors.toList());` but you may consider using a variant that avoids repeating `list.parallelStream()` instead: `Stream<T> stream = list.parallelStream(); if(keyword != null) stream = stream.filter(dto -> dto.getString().contains(keyword)); return stream .map(...) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

```
.filter(getFilter(dto));
```

and

```
private static Predicate getFilter(String dto){
 // logic here. either return Filter A's singleton instance or return Null filter (that allows to pass everything i.e. `(dto)-> true`)
}
```

Comment: So there is no primitive java sugar to user?

Answer (score 0):

since filter is not a ending stream condition. you could add it at anytime. so, how about this?

```
public class ConditionalStreams {

//send your stream, a boolean, and the filter condition
public static Stream<Integer> filterFun(Stream<Integer> stream, boolean needToFilter, Predicate<Integer> filterStream){
        if(needToFilter)
            return stream.filter(filterStream);
        else
            return stream;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);

    // create your filter condition
    Predicate<Integer> filterStream = (num)->num%2==0;

    System.out.println("without filter: ");
    //call the function, pass parameters and return the right stream and process it.
    filterFun(numbers.parallelStream(),false,filterStream)
    .forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("with filter : ");
    filterFun(numbers.parallelStream(),true,filterStream)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
 }
```